# Why do I need permissions in my AndroidManifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin, android-permissions

I am currently trying to remove all unneeded permissions from my `AndroidManifest`, and my first thought was to remove all permissions to see if it would give me an error at build or at run time. When I removed all of them I didn't get failure at build or run time.

Looking a bit deeper I found the generated manifest generated at build at `/app/build/intermediates/manifest/full/debug/AndroidManifest`. The manifest surprisingly had *almost* all of the permissions that I had removed.

**EDIT**

I am trying to ask if it is an acceptable practice for me to leave permissions out of my `AndroidManifest` that I know will be merged from my gradle dependencies at build.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html

Comment: I've read that extensively already but thank you. I edited my post to make my question clearer.

Comment: I think the article sums it up quite well, but to answer your question directly: Yes, it is an acceptable practice.

Comment: @RobVoisey so your app is now depending on a library that you may decide to replace at any moment for its own permissions. I don't think that's a really good idea. Whenever that library does a minor change and decides to clean the unnecessary permissions that they ask, you're in trouble. I don't see why that would be an acceptable practice.

Comment: @njzk2 but the permissions are being added to the generated Manifest correct? therefore removing the library would mean that permission isn't added the next time it is generated.

Comment: @RobVoisey exactly. so if you depend on them, then your app stops working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If manifest merging in gradle is enabled, then you will get all the activities, permissions, and other manifest tags from your dependencies (https://developer.android.com/tools/building/manifest-merge.html). You will need to add only the ones that your app explicitly requires. It is a good practice to add to the app manifest the permissions your app relies on, even if they are duplicated, since your app dependencies might remove those permissions on future versions.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to ask if it is an acceptable practice for me to leave permissions out of my AndroidManifest that I know will be merged from my gradle dependencies at build.

Technically it would work and there's nothing really bad with it now, but the same way you do not keep i.e. unused assets in your app `res/drawables` folders, your manifest should list only these permissions your code requires.